# how to display testimonials in article joomla 3

Tags: joomla

I have different testimonials for each article, how to show the related testimonials in the article joomla, 
Im using  Bxslider module to create testimonials,

creating each testimonials for each article as a module and assigning from menu assignment, any other simple methds to display testimonials for the article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to create a 'testimonials' category. This doesn't need to be a child category. Then add your testimonials as articles to this category.

Then all you need to do is to add a module in a position that is directly under the article.

It's easy!

Comment: While this method would work in some situations. The op has different testimonials for different articles. Child categories would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

One method would be creating a testimonials category with child categories for each article.
Then you can use the newsflash module to show the testimonial articles for the current article.

If you want to continue using bxslider you may be able to set each module to a custom position not used in the template, then use `loadmodule` to load position of the module into the article. Some modules doesn't like working like this though.

If you don't use `loadmodule` you'll need to create menu links for each article so you can set the page assignment.

It would be easier to use the `loadmodule` plugin to insert the module into the article if you can.